# How to compare objects in Vala?

Tags: vala, libgee

I am using a Gee.ArrayList with an own class for content. I want to use the "contains" method of the ArrayList, but I really don't know how to set up an equals-method in my class, so ArrayList uses it to find out if the object is in the ArrayList or not.

Example:

```
class Test : GLib.Object {
    public int number;
    
    public Test(int n) {
        number = n;
    }
    public bool equals (Test other) {
        if (number == other.number) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, in another file:

```
var t = new Gee.ArrayList<Test>();
var n1 = new Test(3);
var n2 = new Test(3);
t.add(n1);
t.contains(n2); // returns false, but I want it to return true
```

Does anybody know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the ArrayList, the [constructor](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gee-0.8/Gee.ArrayList.ArrayList) takes your equality comparator. You can do:

```
var t = new Gee.ArrayList<Test>(Test.equals);
```

and the contains should work as you desire.

Comment: Thanks! In fact you have to cast the Test.equals to EqualFunc:
    var t = new Gee.ArrayList<Test>((EqualFunc) Test.equals)

That did it! :-)